# How can I register an array via an interface and then retrieve the one object via explicit class name

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

I register a bunch of classes using Castle.Windsor that implement an interface `ISearchSource`

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<ISearchSource>().WithService.AllInterfaces());
```

One of these is resolved via a CollecctionResolver

```
public SearchBot(ISearchSource[] searchSources)
```

Good so far.

Now, I want to get one of these (a ViewSearchSource) and it has to be the same one resolved via the constructor above, because I'm within a certain lifestyle)

And resolve it like this

```
Container.Resolve<ViewSearchSource>("ViewSearchSource").Bla();
```

I tried this (and many other things) but it returns me a second (different/separate) object - which I cannot have

```
container.Register(Component.For<ISearchSource>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<ViewSearchSource>()
                                    .Named(typeof(ViewSearchSource).Name));
```

Does anyone know what I need to achieve this?

***Addendum***

I ended up doing this - which is a work-around that requires a static service locator.

```
Container.Resolve<ISearchSource>(typeof(ViewSearchSource).ToString());
```

So basically, this takes all the registered ISearchSource objects (from the 6 or so I registered relying on CollectionResolver) and returns the one which is of type that I pass via string

I would still prefer to be able use constructor injection using the explicit class name `ViewSearchSource` but haven't figured out how to do this yet.

Some kind of forwarding' is required eg `Component.For<I1, I2>` but because I need to split the registration between an `AllInterfaces()` registration and a single Component registration, I cannot see a way to achieve this using Castle

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this - which is a work-around that requires a static service locator.

```
Container.Resolve<ISearchSource>(typeof(ViewSearchSource).ToString());
```

So basically, this takes all the registered ISearchSource objects (from the 6 or so I registered relying on CollectionResolver) and returns the one which is of type that I pass via string

I would still prefer to be able use constructor injection using the explicit class name `ViewSearchSource` but haven't figured out how to do this yet.

Some kind of forwarding' is required eg `Component.For<I1, I2>` but because I need to split the registration between an `AllInterfaces()` registration and a single Component registration, I cannot see a way to achieve this using Castle

Comment: By default Castle Windsor names your components by their full type name; http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx#To_specify_a_name_for_the_component:_8 By using the `Configure` method you can define custom names for your components

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ISubDependencyResolver that relies on naming convention](http://kozmic.net/2009/04/09/convention-based-dependency-injection-with-castle-microkernelwindsor/). Convention over configuration FTW!